# Разрешены ли в Google Play "небиткон-краны"/буксы?

Tags: android, google-play

Приложения которые по сути раздают очки/монеты раз в час/полтора . В свою очередь очки/монеты обмениваются на реальные деньги. При этом показывается реклама и этим зарабатывая. В Google Play есть куча таких приложений. Но разрешены ли они?
Так же разрешены ли буксы (выполнение каких то действий за деньги. Действия например: установка приложения ,написание отзыва/оценки , переход по ссылке и т.д.)?

Comment: Что такое “небиткон-краны”/буксы ?

Comment: Не запрещено. Есть куча приложений с опросами, заданиям и так далее.

Comment: @Kromster краны - это "Приложения которые по сути раздают очки/монеты раз в час/полтора . В свою очередь очки/монеты обмениваются на реальные деньги. При этом показывается реклама и этим зарабатывая." Например такого https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.retwy.rubtap . Обрели популярность с криптой, но сейчас уже есть с любой валютой.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev смущает именно оплата и реклама. То есть не скажет ли Гугл что это запрещено? Или пока не призываешь кликать по рекламе все норм, должно быть? Так же вопрос про призыв устанавливать за "что-то" смущает.